# Where is my database file in xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite

After I build an app with `sqlite`. I have installed SQLite manager in Firefox. Doesn´t help because I really don´t know where is that file. I tried many ways.
And finally I try to find this file

```
 _databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myUsers.db"]];
```

To open with MesaSQLite 
Still have the same problem. Where is my file.

Here is the last way I have used:

```
/Users/{YOUR NAME}/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/{DEVICE ID}/data/Containers/Data/Application/{APPLICATION ID}/
```

I still can not find it. I have open almost every project folders.
Please help me.

Comment: Which database structure you use `CoreData` or `Sqlite3`?

Comment: Library folder is hidden in mac. You need to make it appear to see it. Your db file is in there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont open Library on MacintoshHDD. You need to open Library on your USERName Folder. There,normally library folder is hidden. You need to follow the following to see the hidden files.

Or simply copy paste the path into the search finder on your mac.It will take you directly.

The long way to show hidden Mac OS X files is as follows:

```
     Open Terminal found in Finder > Applications > Utilities.
```

In Terminal, paste the following:

```
      defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES.
           Press return.
       Hold 'alt' on your keyboard, then right click on the Finder icon in the dock and click Relaunch.
```

Comment: Actually I have read thhis method before, and I have tried. I have not found anything. But today I use it again and tried to open every folder (hard work) Finally I found all of db I wanted.

Comment: may be at that time you didnt opened the right folder. I know that it is confusing for the first time. Even I faced the issue at first. I'm glad that your issue is solved.Cheers!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find this using this method :

```
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    NSLog(@"%@",[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory  inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject]);

    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
 }
```

Just copy paste whatever is logged in navigate into the folder where you stored your `sqlite` file

The end result should look like this :

```
~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4D2D127A-7103-41B2-872B-2DB891B978A2/data/Containers/Data/Application/0323215C-2B91-47F7-BE81-EB24B4DA7339/Documents/MyApp.sqlite
```

Please note that the long ID's will obviously be different, as well as the file name.

Comment: I have tried it. Pu it at the last line before @end.
I see nothing.

Comment: You don't see anything logged in the console?
Just try putting the NSLog somewhere in your code, it's the same thing (in a view did load, or in the appdelegate didfinishlaunching)
Is the line at least called?

Comment: I didi it but I got nothing. I tried to move the code many possition.

Comment: damn. What if you put just a small text, does it get called ? like "NSLog(@"hello")";  just to be sure your code reads there... Then try the filemanager call (just the first line of the method in my answer). 
I want to make sure that the lines are called before reviewing this scary method :p

Answer (score 0):

You just following line of code to Log.

```
NSString *databasePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myUsers" ofType:@"db"];
```

Or use below code.

```
NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myUsers" ofType:@"bundle"]];
NSLog(@"%@", bundle);
NSString* test = [bundle pathForResource:@"myUsers" ofType:@"db"];
NSLog(@"%@", test);
NSDictionary* dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[bundle pathForResource:@"Root" ofType:@"plist"]];
NSLog(@"%@", dict);
```

Comment: Here is what I got:
2015-04-21 13:36:00.548 SQLexample[3217:44848] (null)
2015-04-21 13:36:00.549 SQLexample[3217:44848] (null)
2015-04-21 13:36:00.549 SQLexample[3217:44848] (null)
2015-04-21 13:36:00.550 SQLexample[3217:44848] (
    dgdxx,
    ""
)

Comment: Can you please check database name and extension.

Comment: your just go thru this example & tutorial where check weather .db exist or not if not then copy from bundle to location. http://goo.gl/PqaBuB

Answer (score 0):

I am using the [Core Data Editor](http://thermal-core.com/CoreDataEditor/) a lot for my iOS projects. It is compatible with Mac and iOS applications and support XML, SQLite and binary stores, etc. It is free. :-)

http://thermal-core.com/CoreDataEditor/